# Use same google app id for multiple apps for Firebase/Crashlytics

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I have multiple apps with different bundle id, and i want to implement the Firebase/Crashlytics framework in all of my apps. But i don't want to create an app in the firebase console for each of my apps, i want to use one app in the firebase console, and every bundle shares the same firebase app.
Is there a way to share a google app id for more than one bundle id of an ios app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve this natively since you need a unique bundle id for each app and the Google-Info.plist reads from your bundle id too.

You could however pipe data through your own server and send it to firebase.